# how do i get upstream server url in nginx

Tags: nginx, server, load-balancing

I am trying to set host header to upstream server url. So if 2nd server was chosen upon request.  I want proxy_setheader host upstreamServerNname...

I've tried using variable it's empty for some reason. $server_addr gives the address of nginx server itself.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `$host` variable.

```
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
```

> $host
>
> in this order of precedence: host name from the request line, or host name from the “Host” request header field, or the server name
>   matching a request

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables

Comment: request host header is pointing to load balancer not to randomly selected upstream server

Comment: Can you include your config?